# Create a game world map in Photoshop (or other alternatives)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tiles

[image: map example]

I am working on a large world map for a game and need a way to make drawing and design easy.

Once satisfied, photoshop (or alternative) should automatically export each grid tile to an image file so the game engine can do its job for scrolling, loading and rendering.

**But there's some challenges:**

- Tiles are rectangular (not square like the illustration above)
- To save space some marked tiles/positions should automatically save as PNG while others as JPG
- I should be able to design freely as a signle big map/image, and let Photoshop (or alternative) deal with cutting the parts when exporting

Any idea on how one should go about doing this efficiently ? How do the big guys solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'slice' feature to cut the image semi-automatically into several pieces.
Tiles can be rectangular and will be cut automatically.  It's been more than ten years since I used the feature, but as far as I remember, the slices can have different file types, too.

Adobe has a detailed tutorial about slices at
https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/slicing-web-pages.html